# Server is falling down when it hits required files in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, pm2

I have a User Model for generating the schema for saving to my Mongo database. It is contained in /models/user.js.

I have a passport.js strategy file which requires the User file, like so:

`var User = require('../models/user');`

Everything works when I test my routes and project locally, but when I run the server using PM2, I get the following errors:

```
0|dataServ |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
0|dataServ |     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
0|dataServ |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
0|dataServ |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
0|dataServ |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
0|dataServ |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
0|dataServ |     at Function._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/Wrapper.js:48:31)
0|dataServ |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
0|dataServ |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
0|dataServ |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/devadmin/civTechDataService/config/passport.js:5:12)
0|dataServ |     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
0|dataServ |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
0|dataServ |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
0|dataServ |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
0|dataServ |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

This is the error line:

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

// load up the user model
var User = require('../models/user'); // This line is causing the error
```

The (relevant) files and folders are:

```
config 
   - passport.js
models
   - user.js
```

When I restart the server, `dataServ` is listed in green. When I try to hit a route, it crashes and appears as red in PM2.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Is your current directory set the same when you run it in PM2 vs. locally?  If you change `require('../models/user');` to use a path that isn't relative, does that fix it?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what I would swap that path out for?

Comment: It turned out to be an outdated version of Node on the server not like async await!